# WPF ComboBox Font Binding FileFormatException

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, combobox, fonts

I have a WPF Combobox that is binding to

```
Me.fontComboFast.ItemsSource = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies


<ComboBox x:Name="fontComboFast">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{Binding}" FontSize="15" Height="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The following exception occurs.  How would be the best way to clear the Fonts.SystemFontFamilies of any invalid fonts?

'file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Adobe/SING/AssocCache/Generic.otf' file does not conform to the expected file format specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the following sample helped [Sample Font Chooser](http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2006/11/01/sample-font-chooser.aspx)

The following code also excludes symbol fonts that are not usable in my situation:

```
Friend Function IsSymbolFont(ByVal FontFamily As FontFamily) As Boolean
    For Each typeface As Typeface In FontFamily.GetTypefaces()
        Dim Face As New GlyphTypeface

        Try
            If typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(Face) Then
                Return Face.Symbol
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            Return True
        End Try

    Next
    Return False
End Function
```